# How to send end-user ip address with the youtube-dl request and get video download link. or there is another way to not get blocked by youtube

Tags: django, youtube, pythonanywhere, youtube-dl

currently working on a youtube video downloader . using youtube-dl,Django and hosting my project on Pythonanywhere,i almost completed my project but when i send request more then 15-20 youtube block my pythonanywhere server ip. SO i want to ask that how can i solve this blocking problem. free proxies takes too much time to respond. please give me a solution.thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the policies of YouTube have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: i know this but there are tons of youtube downloaders and they are downloading videos without getting blocked. So there is some way to bypass the youtube blocking system

Comment: You mean youtube download plugins for in the browser? You can't centralise downloading from a server without getting blocked, it's just not allowed by youtube and you can't get around it.

Comment: can you give me a solution how can i make a youtube video downloader using django for production purpose.

Comment: no because it's not possible.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that most YouTube downloaders do one of three things:

1. Execute client side code to do the actual download. Instead, what the server/extension does is go through the code to find a file being served.
2. Pay for professional proxy servers sufficient to handle the number of downloads one seeks to make without running into rate limits. Proxies are not expensive.
3. Limit the rate at which downloads are conducted.

Those are the only ways I can see around the blocking problem. Youtube really doesn't want you to do what you are trying to do and has put a lot of thought into stopping it.

Comment: Without proxy servers, you usually are rate limited.  I have built a youtube alexa skill using pythonanywhere and during testing I sent too many request and got a 429 too many requests after about 5 tests